# Simulations Confidence Interval Not Equal to conf_int Results

Tags: python, scipy, statsmodels

Given this simulated data:

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_process import ArmaProcess
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.structural import UnobservedComponents


np.random.seed(12345)
ar = np.r_[1, 0.9]
ma = np.array([1])
arma_process = ArmaProcess(ar, ma)

X = 100 + arma_process.generate_sample(nsample=100)
y = 1.2 * X + np.random.normal(size=100)
```

We build a `UnobservedComponents` model with the first 70 points to run inferences on the last 30 points like so:

```
model = UnobservedComponents(y[:70], level='llevel', exog=X[:70])
f_model = model.fit()

forecaster = f_model.get_forecast(
    steps=30,
    exog=X[70:].reshape(-1, 1)
)
conf_int = forecaster.conf_int()
```

If we observe the mean for the 95% confidence interval, we get the following:

```
conf_int.mean(axis=0)
array([118.19789195, 122.14101161])
```

But when trying to get the same values through model simulations, we don't quite get the same results. Here's the script we run for the simulated boundaries:

```
sim_model = UnobservedComponents(np.zeros(30), level='llevel', exog=X[70:])
res = []
predicted_state = f_model.predicted_state[..., -1]
predicted_state_cov = f_model.predicted_state_cov[..., -1]   
for i in range(1000):
     init_state = np.random.multivariate_normal(
         predicted_state,
         predicted_state_cov
     )
     sim = sim_model.simulate(
         f_model.params,
         30,
         initial_state=init_state)
     res.append(sim.mean())
```

Printing the lower 2.5 and upper 97.5 percentile we get:

```
np.percentile(res, [2.5, 97.5])
array([119.06735028, 121.26810407])
```

As we use model simulations to distinguish signal from noise in data, this difference ended up being big enough to lead to contradictory conclusions. If we make for instance:

```
y[70:] += 1
```

Then according to the first technique we conclude the new `y` carries no signal as its mean is lower than `122.14`. But the same is not true if we use the second technique: as the upper boundary is `121.2`, we conclude that there's signal.

What we are trying to understand now is whether this is expected. Shouldn't the lower and upper 95% confidence interval of both techniques be equal?

Comment: My guess would be that this is mainly small sample problem (but I didn't try to understand the details of your computation). AFAIK, all times series models in statsmodels ignore parameter uncertainty in the forecast confidence interval. You could try with a much larger sample size, 70 observations is very small for estimating time series processes with large persistence.

Comment: Also the forecast is conditional on the last observed value. But, IIUC, then your are using a random intial state in the simulation which you don't correct for in computing the percentiles. If that is correct, then you add additional variance through the random initialization.

Comment: Hi @Josef, I tried running with 8000 points and still upper boundary was `122`.  I also removed the `init_state` computation from the inner loop (at first I thought this value should be there as a way to model all possible initial states values for the kalman filter simulations) but results didn't change much as well (it went to `121.13` and before it was `121.2`.  The thing about ignoring uncertainty in forecasting, this would mean that the interval should be even bigger. Don't quite understand why the simulations results in that different intervals.

Comment: another difference that is relevant for non-linear function is that for the forecast you compute the mean of the percentiles/quantiles, but in the simulation you take the percentile of the mean.It might be better to look at the percentiles at specific horizons in the simulation instead of the mean over all time periods, because the prediction and confidence intervals will change with forecast horizon.

Comment: @Josef I see what you mean! Totally makes sense! Just now I realized that probably taking the average of the percentiles is not an appropriate operation after all. This would mean that actually if I want to get the lower and upper confidence interval for the mean then the simulations technique is what I should be using right?

Comment: @Josef an interesting side note, if we do that than our results becomes identical to `bsts` from R. Looks like I should indeed be using the sampling technique indeed.